# How to enhance brain functioning through neurological stimulation?

Tags: neurology

Many emotional and behavioral dysfunctions, such as bad decision-making (http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/brain/awg177), appear to be symptoms of impaired brain functioning. Conversely, stimulating brain function may alleviate these dysfunctions. For example, electric stimulation of the vagus nerve decreases depression ([source](http://news.wustl.edu/news/pages/25384.aspx)).

**How can brain function be improved through neuroelectrical, neurochemical and/or neurosurgical stimulation?**

I am interested in general answers as well as in answers specifically addressing

- the ventromedial prefrontal cortex,
- the amygdala, and
- the insular cortex,

which, according to the [Somatic Marker Hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somatic_marker_hypothesis), might make up the mechanism behind emotional intelligence.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Can learning be facilitated by transcranial magnetic stimulation?](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/5632/4086)

Comment: This is an interesting and well-supported question, but the scope is *really* broad--it would be entirely reasonable to write a dissertation on any number of components of this one question.

Comment: The question seems to be too broad to be answered in a useful way

Comment: This topic already exists which is called cognitive enhancement, and the neurochemical aspect is called nootropics. There has been huge debate about societal impact of cognitive enhancements, they in fact work, but there has been a debate that it may create a societal inequality that is who do not have the access to cognitive enhancement or those who refuse to receive cognitive enhancement, may get lesser success rate or lesser payment or lesser employment. "Brain dope" is indeed a concept.

Comment: I have read that Cognitive enhancement methods may be useful for specific learning disabilities, intellectual disabilities, depression, etc whereas there are arguments about why healthy and typically developing people too should have access to cognitive enhancements.  There are counterarguments too.

Comment: I dont see any doctors prescribing any kind of cognitive enhancement methods or  nootropics for people suffering intellectual disabilities or dementia. Instead they tend to overuse antipsychotics though antipsychotics reportedly have dementia-inducing effect. Except for very old patients with ssay 80+ and with stroke and other visibly bad neuromotor condition some doctors use nootropics but not all doctors. If a doctor is requested for it, as i saw they usually  yell or laugh or criticise & treat the honest need as paranoia or self-anxiety or delusion. That may be a medical malpractice.

Comment: However i also read that engineers at silicon valley secretly use nootropics and cognitive enhancement for better performance.